# Is it possible to debug API requests on localhost while testing using PHPUnit and PhpStorm?

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I have configuration that tests my localhost API succesfully in PhpStorm using PHPUnit. Also I can stop on breakpoints but only inside my TestCase classes.

I need to stop on breakpoints that are set inside logic that are tested, but it does not stop there.

Testing command:

```
/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 /foo/vendors/composer/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /foo/_stuff/phpunit/config-api2.xml --teamcity
```

My config xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    bootstrap="../../foo/tests/app_test_case.php"
    colors="true"
    stopOnFailure="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="foo">
            <file>../../foo.php</file>
        </testsuite>
```

Added to php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

Added to requested route:

```
?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM
```

And added cookie in index.php:

```
header('Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

The question here is how you are going to start a debug session for those API calls.

The most usual way would be adding `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` to php.ini for the interpreter running the calls, so that a debug session would start for every single PHP call, API or not.

If you are not happy with it, you can add the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` GET-parameter to HTTP requests of the calls, but that would obviously require code modification.

Comment: Updated main post. It still not stopping on my breakpoints in logic code

Comment: It's worth looking at the [Xdebug remote log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544819-How-to-collect-remote-log-for-XDebug) then.

Comment: in xdebug log it says about breakpoint that did not hit:  `<- breakpoint_set -i 31 -t line -f file:///home/pawel/PhpstormProjects/foo/bar/controllers/api_baz_controller.php -n 44
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="31" id="308570025"></response>`

Comment: This line means that PhpStorm is informing Xdebug that it has certain breakpoints, it doesn't mean that it's the correct debug session or that the breakpoint has been reached.

I think I owe you some explanations. You have probably added `remote_autostart` to php.ini of the CLI interpreter. That's wrong because what you need to debug is a web request, and thus Xdebug should be configured for the web server interpreter.

Is the web server you make requests to local? If so, please load phpinfo() with it and confirm that that Xdebug is configured properly.

Comment: fck, path mapping was the problem, everything else was ok